# Differential equation involving evaluation of solution at a point

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm working on the differential equation:
$$u_t(t,x,y) = u_y(t,x,y) + u_{xy}(t,1,1) \cdot u_x(t,x,y)    $$

I haven't seen anything like this before in my courses, any ideas of what we could do? Would characteristics be appropriate here?

Thanks!

Comment: So $u_t(x,y,t) = u_y(x,y,t) + u_{xy}(1,1,t)u_x(x,y,t)$?

Comment: That's correct, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step, the pde can be easily "solved" by the method of characteristics to achieve

$$
u(t,x,y) = C(x+\phi(t),y+t)\\
\phi'(t)=u_{xy}(t,1,1)
$$
Assuming you have inital conditions at $t=0$, namely $u(0,x,y)=C(x+\phi(0),y)=u_0(x,y)$ we can eliminate $C$ and end up with
$$
u(t,x,y)=u_0(x-\phi(0)+\phi(t),t+y)\\
\phi'(t)=(u_0)_{xy}(1-\phi(0)+\phi(t),1+t)
$$
So, if you have a specific sufficiently smooth initial condition $u_0$ you can solve the second equation, get $\phi(t)$ and subsequently get an (explicit) solution $u$.

Example for $u_0=x^2y$:
$$
\Rightarrow \phi'(t)=2(1-\phi(0)+\phi(t))\\
\Rightarrow\phi(t)=\phi(0)+e^{2t}-1\\
\Rightarrow u(t,x,y)=(x+e^{2t}-1)^2(t+y)
$$

Note: this relatively easy approach works only for $\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^2$. Otherwise the first part will remain the same but the function $C$ will look different.

Comment: Could you explain how you eliminate $C$?

Comment: If we are considering the shift in the first variable, can simply replace it by $u_0$ due to C(x+\phi(0),y)=u_0(x,y)$.